# HTML link escaping url passed as query string

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following link:

`$this->Html->link('admin',array('admin'=>true,'controller'=>'users','action'=>'login','?'=>array('continue'=>$this->here)))`

Which should produce a link like: `http://domain.com/admin/login?continue=/location`

However it always escapes the `/` so I get a link like: `http://domain.com/admin/login?continue=%2Flocation`

How do I stop this? I tried `array('escape'=>false)` in the link but that only escapes the link itself rather than the `href`.

Comment: may I ask why you use _GET params instead of named params? from the looks of your domain mod_rewrite is available on your system. that'd save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: Wouldn't it look odd if I did: `http://domain.com/admin/login/continue:/location`

Comment: well, passing any special characters to an url always looks odd. base64encode or at least url_encode is the least you should do then to get a valid url (which cake does here for you). you can always "undo" the encoding afterwards.

Comment: Could you show what you mean? I'd prefer to use GET params as it's the standard way of doing things like this BUT I don't want it escaping the `/`

Comment: Nothing to do with Cake; it's standard behaviour as far as I'm aware. Wordpress does the same (encodes the slashes) when logging in and redirecting. Not sure if it's browser specific or language specific but I don't believe there's a solution. It's purely aesthetic anyway so is it really worth worrying about. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949173/how-can-i-stop-the-browser-from-url-encoding-form-values-on-get) for further discussion.

Comment: @Ross Not true as I have seen sites that don't have the slashes encoded!

Answer (score 0):

You either need to manually add this part to the url after it went through cake:

```
$this->Html->url(...).'?continue=/location'
```

which I don't recommend (likely invalid url!)

or you use url_decode() in the target action to receive the correct string again (should cake usually do automatically, as well).
check what the $this->request->params[named][location] key contains:

```
array('admin'=>true,'controller'=>'users','action'=>'login','continue'=>$this->here)
```

ops. in 1.3 it is still $this->params[named][location] !

Comment: So what do I write for my Html link to do it then? As I still don't properly follow...

Comment: As I already pointed out - it SHOULD encode it. otherwise it is part of the url. and you obviously want to pass it as "content". and as such it has to be encoded. either cake style (solution above) or base64encoded.

Comment: I've seen it NOT encoded in urls so it's perfectly plausible and possible to have a url passed as content and not encoded.