# Passing get values mangles my urls

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Just upgraded from 1.3 to 2.0.3 and I'm trying to migrate all the changes.  I'm noticing that the following line

```
echo $this->Html->link('Quote', array('controller'=>'crm_quotes', 'action'=>'index', $lead['id'].'/'.$crmContact['CrmContact']['id']), null);
```

builds the url `"/crm_quotes/index/15/21"`. When I click the link I'm taken to url:

```
"/crm_quotes/index/15%2F212
```

so it's replacing the characters with the html `#` but it's ultimately breaking the link.

When I manually edit the URL to the correct one:

```
"/crm_quotes/index/15/21"
```

the page loads.

Can someone enlighten me? Should I be using the `url` function rather than link?

I have a lot of pages that need multiple parameters passed in the url. I was using named parameters but after reading some comments by Mark Story I decided to stop the named parameters as he hinted at their possible removal from future versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the extra parameters the correct (cake) way. Cake encodes any `/` in the URL that it didn't specifically set; I haven't found out how to prevent this yet.

```
echo $this->Html->link('Quote', array('controller'=>'crm_quotes', 
                              'action'=>'index', 
                               $lead['id'],
                               $crmContact['CrmContact']['id']), null);
```

Answer (score 0):

As an answer for your problem: just take the concatenated '/' out and pass the IDs as separate values in that array. It should place forward slashes between them automatically.

```
echo $this->Html->link('Quote', array(
    'controller'=>'crm_quotes', 
    'action'=>'index', 
    $lead['id'],
    $crmContact['CrmContact']['id']
));
```

On the topic of encoding: I think the problem here is that it doesn't know that you intend for the / to be treated as a valid part of the URL instead of just some text. The default behavior is to encode reserve characters to avoid this problem, so it gets URL encoded.

Here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021312/html-link-escaping-url-passed-as-query-string), and an answer about [URL encoding in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949173/how-can-i-stop-the-browser-from-url-encoding-form-values-on-get).