# Form encoding URL

Tags: php, forms, submit, decode

I have a form which passing name to self:

```
<form>
    <input name=page size=100 value="<?=htmlspecialchars($url)?>">
    <input type=submit value="Open">
    <input type=button onclick="this.parentNode.style.display = 'none'" value="Close">
</form>
```

After it takes by `$_GET["page"]` In form when clicking open the Url looks like `http://mysite.co` 
and `$_GET["page"]` is the same, but in browser navigation bar it looks like `/?page=http%3A%2F%2mysite.co`
How to remove encoding when i submit the form `?` To get navigation bar status like 
 `/?page=http://mysite.co`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this method

```
htmlspecialchars
```

from

```
    <input name=page size=100 value="<?=htmlspecialchars($url)?>">
```

to be

```
    <input name=page size=100 value="<?=$url?>">
```

After searching a while i found this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949173/how-can-i-stop-the-browser-from-url-encoding-form-values-on-get)

Actually you can't do this but you may decode this URL for further use.

Comment: I was trying it, but no result

Comment: Try This `$url = htmlspecialchars_decode ($_GET['page']);`

Comment: thanks but it didnt help, mayble some server settings?

Answer (score 1):

Use

htmlspecialchars_decode();

Also, avoid short open tags, they're disabled by default on most PHP installations, so will cause you a headache down the line if you move server, etc.

Comment: Yeah i know about short tags, its on my virtual local mashine for test. I need to disable encode slashesh.