# Changes in angular 2 urls after reload

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have urls with `queryParams` and `params` in my angular 2 app. And i'm stuck with problem: after reloading pages my urls distorted.

with `params`:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/albums?user_id=1

after reload:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/albums/?user_id=1

with `queryParams`:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/albums/%3Aid;id=13

after reload:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/albums/%3Aid%3Bid%3D13

routes.ts

```
import { ModuleWithProviders }  from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent }  from './components/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent }  from './components/register/register.component';
import { AlbumsComponent }  from './components/albums/albums.component';
import { AddAlbumComponent }  from './components/albums/add-album.component';
import { AddImageAlbumComponent }  from './components/albums/add-image-album.component';
import { AlbumDetailComponent }  from './components/albums/album-detail.component';
import { PhotosComponent }  from './components/photos/photos.component';
import { UsersComponent }  from './components/users/users.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './guards/auth.guard'

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
    { path: 'albums', component: AlbumsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'add-album', component: AddAlbumComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'add-image-album/:id', component: AddImageAlbumComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'albums/:id', component: AlbumDetailComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'photos', component : PhotosComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'users', component : UsersComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

navigation with `params`:

```
[routerLink]="['/albums/:id', {id: album.id}]
```

navigation with `queryParams`:

```
[queryParams]="{user_id: dataService.getCurrentUserId()}"
```

Comment: Looks like something wrong with your navigation code. Can you show your component where you handle navigation.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

After url decoding your reloaded queryparams url, I get this:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/albums/:id;id=13`

It is essentially the same as your original url, but with the params fully url encoded.

**Update:**

If you need a reference on how to force decode the url, you can look at [this previous stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949173/how-can-i-stop-the-browser-from-url-encoding-form-values-on-get)

Answer (score 0):

Pass the param in  RouteLink itself for exmaple see the below code

```
[routerLink]="[/albums,nav.param]"
```

And in Routing declare like this

```
{ path: 'albums/:id', component: AlbumsComponent }
```

And in albumscomponent.ts read the url param value using activateroute.